# Search for month or year in a date using Linq based on condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable, where-clause

I want to explain my situation first:

I have a `DataTable` which is shown in a `DataGridView`. I also have a `Textbox` to search values in a specific column. For date values this looks like this (searchInDt is my DataTable, getSelectedItem is the column name and searchBox is the TextBox)

```
searchInDt.CaseSensitive = false;
var rowSources = (from myRow in searchInDt
                                .AsEnumerable()
                                .Where(myRow => myRow.Field<DateTime>(getSelectedItem)
                                                    .ToString()
                                                    .StartsWith(searchBox.Text))
                  select myRow);

if (rowSources.Any())
    dataGridView1.DataSource = rowSources.CopyToDataTable();
```

So this works but Now I have a `CheckBox` where I can choose between month and year. How does it work if I want to search from position 3 of a `DateTime` value (for month) or from position 6 (year)?
I tried Skip but this does not work. Even trying `EndsWith` (which would not be exactly that what I'm looking for) does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than checking against the `string` value of `DateTime`, you can check directly against the `Month`/`Year` properties of the `DateTime` field.

Set the value of `isMonth` based on the CheckBox selection, then

```
var isMonth = <true if Month is selected, false if Yaer is selected>;
var query = int.Parse(searchBox.Text);
var rowSources = searchInDt.AsEnumerable()
                           .Where(row => isMonth ? row.Field<DateTime>(getSelectedItem).Month == query
                                                 : row.Field<DateTime>(getSelectedItem).Year == query);
```

On a side note, you should use a `RadioButton` instead, as generally `CheckBox`s are used to select multiple values, and you do not want the user to select both month and year.

Comment: Didn't know one can search for months and years. Thanks for that! But this does not work for me somehow (same like EndsWith). The if statement does not contain any result (if (rowSources.Any()))

Comment: First check if that is a data issue.

Comment: Ok. I tried this with the equal sign know and it works. Any chance to do this with StartsWith (for the month) ? Thanks for this solution!

Comment: I'd not recommend that. `StartsWith` is a `string` method, you cannot use that with `DateTime`. To use `StartsWith` you need to convert the date to string with `.ToString()` first, but you'll loose type safety and make the code error prone. If you really want that, you can do something like `dateValue.ToString("MMddyyyy").StartsWith(monthSearchString)`.